# Can't get a simple Laravel Login controller setup to work

Tags: php, laravel

I am just starting with Laravel after finally deciding to move from CodeIgniter, however I cannot get a simple login form to work. I keep getting that "MethodNotAllowedHttpException" error.

Here is how my Controller looks

```
class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function login()
    {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        Login::login($username, $password); 
        // ^ Call to Login model to check the user's credentials - everything fine there
    }

}
```

Here is my view

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'LoginController/login')) }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
        {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
{{ Form::close }}
```

And my route for this is like

`Route::get('LoginController/login', 'LoginController@login');`

I'm doing something horribly wrong somewhere, can you guys please point it out?

Thanks!

Comment: With that route configuration you should get access via: `http://example.com/LoginController/login`, does it work for you?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo Yes, I can open http://example.com/LoginController/login, however the form is not working, I get that "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException" error.

Comment: When you said the form _is not working_. What do you mean? Is when you submit the form or when you are accessing via the route?

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo When I click the submit button, I get to r

Comment: Got it! You need to route the POST verb: `Route::post('LoginController/login', 'LoginController@login');`

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo When I click the submit button; then. Accessing via route is just fine and shows that "Undefined index: username" which is expected.

Comment: That should be another question, but I will provide another suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are just routing the `GET` method. You should also route the `POST` method to make your controller work:

```php
Route::get('LoginController/login', 'LoginController@login');
Route::post('LoginController/login', 'LoginController@login');
```

Normally, It is better to have to separate methods in your controller to handle different logic. Something as follow:

```php
Route::get('login', 'LoginController@showLogin');
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@processLogin');
```

That way you will have your controller's methods more specific, one that just show the login page, and the other that actually do the login process.

---

**Update**

If you want to retrieve input values within Laravel, you should use the `Input` class, so you will replace your current code:

```php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

to be as follow:

```php
$username = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password');
```

Happy coding!

Comment: You are welcome @JohnSmith! I just added a personal suggestion in current answer.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was about to ask something like that. I'll want the user accessing it directly to go somewhere else, and post request to do something else.

Comment: Not really @JohnSmith, Laravel is!

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a form method as POST so that it reads

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'LoginController/login', 'method'=>'POST')) }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
        {{ Form::submit('Submit') }}
{{ Form::close }}
```

And the in your routes file add the following

```
Route::post('/login', array('uses' => 'LoginController@login')
```